# Input text validation while input?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

In my html page i want user to add a string in specific order in `input type=text`.

if i use pattern in input tag then the error will pop while submiting form and i want it while typing.

The required pattern is `4Letters and then 4Numbers No white Space No Special Character Allowed`

The Pattern i used in my backend is `^[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{4}$`

How can i achieve this ?

**Edit**

To The Moderators :
**I Never said that the error was because of typo. Where did i mentioned it ? Closing question did not provides solution whoever it was you should have read the thread.**

I haven't accepted answers as they are not working as intended.
Working on the solution.

Need this thread to opened again. Thank you

Comment: You swapped the letters and numbers in the pattern, try `pattern="\d{4}[A-Za-z]{4}"`

Comment: I want to disallow while tying if the pattern is not matched how can i do that ?

Comment: @ChandraShekharAazad what do you want to disallow ? A button ?

Comment: No, let me try to explain: the user in text input is typing the string, (the format/pattern of string is mentioned in the main question), after uer enters 4letter now user needs to enter 4number but if the user enter a letter the input text should not allow that letter. and all this i want while typing.

Comment: @ChandraShekharAazad Then you should implement javascript that removes the letter if it's in position 4 or later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried by adding a function call on **input changes**, so when the user will be typing it will test if the user input matches the **pattern** or not.

### Note

- Pattern : `^[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{4}$` matches the string like this `1234ABCD`
- For changing the Pattern, we require to do 3 changes

  1. In `HTML` input field, we need to update the pattern
  2. In `JS` the `testText` we need to update the string

     - `testText` contains, sample string that fully matches the pattern
  3. (Optional) According to the requirement we can update the `textElem.innerHTML` value.

```js
const textElem = document.querySelector(".text__error");

function checkText(event) {
    let testText = "1234ABCD"; // sample string that fully matches the pattern
    const { target } = event;
    if (!target.checkValidity()) {
        const { value } = target;
        testText = value + testText.slice(value.length);
        const re = new RegExp(event.target.pattern);
        if (!re.test(testText)) {
            target.value = value.substr(0, value.length - 1);
            if (!target.checkValidity()) {
                textElem.innerHTML = "Invalid, e.g. 1234ABCD ";
            } else {
                textElem.innerHTML = "Valid";
            }
        } else {
            textElem.innerHTML = "";
        }
    } else {
        textElem.innerHTML = "Valid";
    }
}
```

```html
<form action="">
    <p>Text :
        <input type="text" pattern="^[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{4}$" required oninput="checkText(event)">
        <span class="text__error"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

there is risk of getting downvoted :) but still here is my solution. I tried to solve it using one regex but that didn't work so i used two regex to check the pattern and i am removing the last element from string if it is invalid.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#typehere').keyup(function(el) {
    let valid = true;
    let regex = /^\d{0,4}$/;
    let regex1 = /^\d{0,4}[a-zA-Z]{0,4}$/;
    if (this.value.length < 5) {
      valid = regex.test(this.value)
    } else {
      valid = regex1.test(this.value)
    }
    if (!valid) {
      console.log(valid)
      this.value = this.value.substr(0, this.value.length - 1);
    }

  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="typehere" />
```